# SQL - operate on current condition row

Tags: sql

I'd like to illustrate my question using a free sql 'simulator':
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

Assume please I am given a list of subject/winner pairs (i put them in the WHERE..OR clauses) and want them ALL to be listed back in the result with an additional flag 'Is in DB?' Y/N.

I tried to prepare sth like:

```
select subject, winner, 
( case 
  when winner is null then 'N'
  else 'Y'
) as "Is in DB?" 
from nobel 
where (subject='Literature' and winner='Saint-John Perse')
or (subject='Medicine' and winner='Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet')
or (subject='Medicine' and winner='Peter Medawar')
or (subject='Medicine' and winner='Christiano Ronaldo')
```

Only the last OR condition won't give back any result.
Despite that i would also like it to be listed with flag N, otherwise i wouldn't put the CASE sentence to get all the existing rows.

Not sure either if the CASE sentence is correct at all. Tried also

```
case winner when is null then 'N'
```

Possibly some SELECT IN SELECT or temporary table? Kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with check_data (subject, winner) as (
   values 
     ('Literature', 'Saint-John Perse'), 
     ('Medicine', 'Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet'),
     ('Medicine', 'Peter Medawar'),
     ('Medicine', 'Christiano Ronaldo')
) 
select cd.subject, 
       cd.winner, 
       case 
       when 
         winner is null then 'N'
         else 'Y'
       end as "Is in DB?" 
from check_data cd.
  left join nobel n 
     on n.subject = cd.subject  
    and n.winner = cd.winner
```

Not all DBMS support the "anonymous" row-constructor using `values` though. So you might need some dummy select in the common table expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Temp Table (Subject nVarchar(50), Winner nVarchar(50))

Insert  @Temp   (Subject, Winner)
    Values  ('Literature' ,'Saint-John Perse'),
        ('Medicine' ,'Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet'),
        ('Medicine' ,'Peter Medawar'),
        ('Medicine' ,'Christiano Ronaldo')

select  subject, winner, 
    ( case 
      when nobel.Winner is null then 'N'
      else 'Y'
    ) as [Is in DB?] 
    from nobel Left Outer Join @Temp  A
        On nobel.Subject = A.Subject And nobel.Winner = A.Winner
```

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, you can't get something from nothing, you need to have the domain to select from. Using a temp table like  Meysam Tolouee does is one way, Another is:

```
select x.subject, x.winner
     , case when y.subject is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as is_in_db
from ( 
    select 'Literature' as Subject
         , 'Saint-John Perse' as Winner
    union
    select 'Medicine' as Subject
         ,'Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet' as Winner
    union
    select 'Medicine' as Subject
         ,'Peter Medawar' as winner
    union
    select 'Medicine' as subject
         ,'Christiano Ronaldo' as winner
) as x
left join nobel y
    on x.subject = y.subject
   and x.winner = y.winner

Literature  Saint-John Perse    Y
Medicine    Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet Y
Medicine    Peter Medawar   Y
Medicine    Christiano Ronaldo  N
```